# How do I make a column in SQL that's an array of data in .NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have my models page, but one thing I can't seem to do is get a property to be a List/Array.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVCPractuce.Models
{
    public class Stoof
    {
        public int StoreID { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        public int StoreYear { get; set; }
        public decimal StoreCost { get; set; }
        public string StoreMotto { get; set; }
        public int StoreLikes { get; set; }
        public List<string> StoreItems { get; set; }

        public Stoof()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I get the error of could not be mapped because it is of type List which is not supported primitive type. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Should that not be another table, which is foreign-keyed on this?

Comment: SQL is a relational database. To achieve the above structure you have to create a new database table StoofStoreItems which will have two columns, `StoofId` and `ItemName`. Then instead of `List<string>` you change have `ICollection<StoofStoreItems>`.

Comment: Hi @Jason,any update about this case? Does my solution helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public ICollection StoreItems { get; set; }

ICollection needs to be type of StoreItems. Then add foreign key ref into StoreItems entity for proper mapping

Answer (score 0):

One way is as mentioned above, you can create a new class and then use one-to-many relationship.

Another way is to convert it,you can use following code:

In you context(`using System.Text.Json;`)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
 //...
 builder.Entity<Stoof>()
        .Property(e => e.StoreItems)
        .HasConversion(
          v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, default),
          v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(v, default));
 //...
}
```

Migration and update database.

Test result:

[image]